# Full Calendar events not displaying from database in Handlebars Express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fullcalendar, handlebars.js

I'm injecting the data into the handlebars calendar page via event as shown in the controller bellow

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Event.find().then((events) => {
    console.log(events);
    res.render('calendar', { title: 'Calendar', calendarlink: true, event: events });
  }, (err) => {
    res.status(400).send(err);
  })
});
```

The data is showing in the console log but I cannot get it to display on the calendar.hbs
this is the code for the calendar hbs

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'title',
        center: 'agendaDay,agendaWeek,month',
        right: 'prev,next today'
    },
    firstDay: 1, //  1(Monday) this can be changed to 0(Sunday) for the USA system
    defaultView: 'month',
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap3',
    events: {{event}},
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/> " + event.description);
        $(element).tooltip({
            title: "Description: " + event.description
        });
    }
 })
```

The event option looks like this with the rendered JSON:

```
events: { 
  _id: 5a0757fa94aad82784cbf8a1, 
  title: 'SampleEvent', 
  start: 2017-11-11T22:34:00.000Z, 
  end: 2017-11-15T07:00:00.000Z, 
  address: 'Paris HQ, LA', 
  description: 'Get ready to live a moment of your lifetime', 
  __v: 0 
},
{ 
  _id: 5a0761055876ab10dc00a71f, 
  title: 'NewEvent', 
  start: 2017-11-06T08:00:00.000Z, 
  end: 2017-11-06T15:00:00.000Z, 
  address: 'digital hub', 
  description: 'All are invited', 
  __v: 0 
},
```

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? What does `{{event}}` look like when rendered in JSON format? There's nothing obviously wrong with the rest of your client-side code (I don't know about node.js so perhaps that's an issue, unfortunately I can't say for certain, but it looks plausible).

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: events: { _id: 5a0757fa94aad82784cbf8a1,
  title: &#x27;SampleEvent&#x27;,
  start: 2017-11-11T22:34:00.000Z,
  end: 2017-11-15T07:00:00.000Z,
  address: &#x27;Paris HQ, LA&#x27;,
  description: &#x27; Get ready to live a moment of your lifetime&#x27;,
  __v: 0 },{ _id: 5a0761055876ab10dc00a71f,
  title: &#x27;NewEvent&#x27;,
  start: 2017-11-06T08:00:00.000Z,
  end: 2017-11-06T15:00:00.000Z,
  address: &#x27;digital hub&#x27;,
  description: &#x27;All are invited&#x27;,
  __v: 0 },

Comment: The JSON looks invalid to me. events should be an array e.g. `events: [{ _id: "123" //..etc }]`. Also your ID and date values are strings and need to be within single quotes. Assuming you've copied all of that accurately from your page, then that's why you've got a syntax error - the browser can't parse the JSON.